# Sharing email Content using share charm

Tags: c#, windows-8

So I want to share email content to a target application.
So rite now what m doing is manually selecting the email content and then, from share charm sharing it.

So for instance consider following email,

Hi ABC,

Hello How are you.
Test email.

Thank you,
CodeR.

So is there a way by which I can directly share this email to a target app that targets HTML in windows 8?? or the only way is user has to select the text using mouse, once the text is selected then go to share charm and share.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to change the behavior of the Windows 8 Mail App.
The answer is, you can't. When Microsoft developed their Mail app, they have developed it so that a user has to select text before they can share it via share charm.
The Mail apps application logic is outside of your control, so there is nothing you can do.